# More compact layout

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, pyqt4

In the following code, I'd like to get rid of the margin around the buttons.  I'd like to have the buttons stretch all the way to the edge of the frame.  How can I do that?

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.setSpacing(0)
window.setLayout(layout)
for i in range(2):
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton())
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
layout.setContentsMargin(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Ah yes sorry, i was doing it by memory there, and i normally let KDevelop4 do at least part of the typing for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a working Qt at hand to try right now, but I believe you might get your wish by using [style](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyle.html) sheets with both *margins* and *padding* set to 0 (you might also need to tweak the [size policy](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsizepolicy.html), as it might otherwise block the widgets from some kind of stretching your style requires).